# Resizing QTableWidget Columns and Rows to Fill Table

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget with an N number of columns, which when the number of columns are set, they automically fill in the entire QTableWidget. When I try to dynamically change the number of columns to N/2 columns, the size of each column does not change. This results in the right half the QTableWidget being nothing but whitespace.

Conversly, if I were it reset the column count to 2*N, the column widths adjust themselves appropriately and fill the QTableWidget.

I'm wondering how I can reset the number of columns and row without the QTableWidget having any whitespace?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `QHeaderView`'s Resize Mode?

```
    QTableWidget* myTable = new QTableWidet;
    QHeaderView* header = myTable->horizontalHeader();
    header->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Edit: As pointed out, in Qt 5:

```
    QTableWidget* myTable = new QTableWidet;
    QHeaderView* header = myTable->horizontalHeader();
    header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Comment: This works. However, `setSectionResizeMode` should be used instead. `setResizeMode` is not available in Qt5. However, it seems I have to reset the mode every time I update the row or column count.

Comment: [QHeaderView::setStretchLastSection(true)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop) might also be an option, depending on your application.

Comment: `myTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)` in pyqt5